# Django Upstream Caching (Vary On Headers) Not working

Tags: django, caching, http-headers

I have a view which displays user specific, meaning the content of the response for the same URL is unique per individual authenticated user.

Ideally, these pages would be cached in the browser.  However, that does not appear to be the case in Chrome or Firefox (on production or locally).

The development server is processing the view each time, despite the fact that I've set the @vary_on_cookies decorator.

I have the right middleware in place (in the right order):

```
  django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware                                               
  django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware
```

Do I need to set CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = False?

One thing that I've noticed is that the request is sending this cache control header:

```
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
```

I assume that that might be the root problem.  Or is this related to the development server?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Confused. This is exactly the behavior it *should* have. The cache is not user-specific, i.e. you don't have one cache for User A and another cache for User B. You just have a cache for the entire site. The template is specifically *not* cached because it varies based on the user.

Comment: A given user should experience upstream caching, based on their cookies

Comment: How did you solve this? My cache is displaying the cached data of user 1 to user 2